# Как убрать пункт Home из меню в Joomla 3.x?

Tags: html, вёрстка, joomla, cms, menu

Как сделать так, что бы пункт Home не отображался в меню, и при этом страница Home работала как страница по умолчанию и на нее можно было бы попасть нажав на иконку сайта?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul#menu li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Этот ответ вполне понятен. Только я не разобрался как пользоваться #menu в данном случае. Но вместо #menu можно дописать пару родительских классов, например так: .nav-collapse > .menu > li:first-child { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

Есть второй способ скрыть пункты меню в joomla - можно создать скрытое меню и переместить в него пункты, которые нужно скрыть.

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой вариант - в нужном меню выбрать пункт, который будет главной страницей. Тогда пункт меню `home` можно скрыть, либо удалить.